# PyMongo TypeError

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a python script in which I'm using pymongo to aggregate collections and perform certain operations on them if the sum of a particular aggregate is greater than a number (in this case, 30).

```
  agg = collection.aggregate([{"$match":{"valid":1}}, {"$group": {"_id": {"createdby" : "$createdby" ,"addedtime" : "$addedtime", "empname" : "$empname"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}}])

  cnt = 0
  for eachAgg in agg:
    print "eachAgg = ",eachAgg
    if eachAgg['count'] >= 30:
```

When I run this script, I'm getting

```
  eachAgg = ok
  Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
  if eachAgg['count'] >= 30: 
  TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I don't understand how `$sum` aggregate is not an integer.

Comment: `eachAgg` is a string and `'count'` is obviously a string, hence `eachAgg['count']` is causing `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: @DeepSpace When I perform query `db.tme_count.find({"count": {$type:2}})`, I get no result but `db.tme_count.find({"count": {$type:16}})` gives me a list of documents.
Any reason behind this?

Comment: Also `> typeof db.tme_count.findOne().count` gives me
`number`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`agg:` returns a more detailed dict with the result of aggregation i.e.:

```
    { 
      u'ok': 1.0, 
      u'waitedMS': 0L, 
      u'result': [<your actual aggregation result>]
    }
```

That's why you get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, cause you iterate over keys in the dict (`for eachAgg in agg`) , where a key is  string and string indices must be integers.

The real data result it is in `agg['result']`, try:

```
for eachAgg in agg['result']:
    if eachAgg['count'] >= 30:
    ....
```